# Como adicionar uma view já construída a uma controller com asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Criei uma view(Razor Page) em um projeto Asp.Net Core 2.0. Como eu a construir do zero e necessito agora atribuir uma controller a ela. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

A sua `View` tem que estar dentro de uma pasta com o mesmo nome do `Controller` (porém sem o 'Controller'. Digamos que o seu `Controller` se chame `CompanyController`, o nome da pasta da `View` desse `Controller` irá se chamar apenas `Company`) e dentro de uma pasta chamada `Views`. Abaixo temos um exemplo.

Digamos que a sua `View` esteja dentro de uma pasta chamada `Company`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, eu tenho 5 `views` dentro da pasta `Company`.

Com base no que falei acima, você deve então ter um `Controller` chamado `CompanyController` e este deve estar dentro de uma pasta chamada `Controller`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, dentro do seu `Controller`, você vai ter algo parecido com isso:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Onde o método `Index()` é responsável por chamar a sua `View`, de nome `Index`, dentro da pasta `Company`.

Answer (score 0):

Só criar uma classe na pasta controller e colocar a page que você quer renderizar:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```